# Best way to execute code at given datetime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, notifications

I'd just like to know which method would be the best to execute a function at a given date in JS. My first idea is to make a loop running in a web worker checking each minute if I'm in the minute where I'm supposed to display my notification, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to make it.

Any idea ?

PS : I don't really need any answer because I'm using the [cordova plugin local-notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) and I'm using the 'at' argument, this question is for pure curiosity/learning.

**EDIT :**
Some of you find the question too broad, in fact it's broad, not too broad (I'm not asking "How to send notifications ?") and that's all the point, I'm looking for a general algorithm/explanation to have a rich answer here, so explanations for any platforms are welcomed to help to grasp the differences of the problem each time.

Comment: Where is this going to run? Node? Mobile application?

Comment: I would imagine the best way would be to work out how long until the target time, then use`setTimeout`.

Comment: Anywhere, it's really pure curiosity. If you can give me explanation on both it would be perfect!

Comment: Try your idea and then if/when you run into problems come back and ask specific code related questions then

Comment: For a bit of accuracy without too many unnecessary calls, you can set a timer to run at say 95% of the difference between now and the target date. Keep calling it at 95% and when the difference gets to less than say 1 minute, just set it to the final time.

Comment: You can use setTimeout, but when page refresh then you lose whole information but even so you can log when you display your notication via localstorage then next visit you can go where you last stayed or can add passed time and display.

Comment: *Some of you find the question too broad, in fact that's all the point* Well, then it's not really a good question for Stack Overflow, since broad questions get closed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it really depends on your where your application will live. If its in the browser, node, etc.

The simplest but also fragile solution would be to calculate the difference in milliseconds between now and the execution time. Then just `setTimeout()` with that difference. But if the browser refreshes, then of course that timeout is gone unless you run the same thing again.

But without knowing more about the structure and nature of your application, its difficult to get any more specific.

Comment: Interesting! I think if the magic runs in a web worker, the browser refreshed shouldn't be a problem right ?

Comment: You're not getting any benefit out of using a webworker for this kind of thing. If the browser refreshes, the workers get killed. They don't persist. If you need some full-proof scheduler, you need a backend service that the app can either poll or connect via a websocket to receive notifications.

Comment: Okay it makes sense, so I can consider that the time checking mecanic should be on server side and send a real time message to the client, which will make a job of showing the notification. Seems like a good solution especially for cross platform apps!

Comment: I upvote you because you gave me good informations without trying to attack my question. Thank you very much ^_^